# Android AutoCompleteTextView Custom Drop Down with Data from Web

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I got AutoCompleteTextView to work with the default drop down. I am now trying to figure out if I can get a custom drop down to work with my data. I feel pretty close, but I cannot get the drop down to display.
Here is what I am trying to do.

I created a custom adapter.

```
public class UserSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserSearchItem> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater vi;
int count = 0;

public UserSearchAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    this.context = context;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    final UserSearchItem i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        Log.d("adapter", "in here");
        UserSearchItem si = (UserSearchItem) i;
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.user_search_item, null);
        final TextView title = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_userSearchName);
        if (title != null)
            title.setText(si.userName);
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

Here is my UserSearchItem Class

```
public class UserSearchItem {

public final String userName;
public final String userId;
public final String userFBId;

public UserSearchItem(String userName, String userId, String userFBId) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userFBId = userFBId;
}

}
```

Here is where I implement the AutoCompleteTextView

```
userSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_UserSearch);
    AutoCompleteAdapter = new UserSearchAdapter(this);
    userSearch.setAdapter(AutoCompleteAdapter);
    userSearch.addTextChangedListener(this);

    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (shouldAutoComplete) {
        new DoAutoCompleteSearch().execute(s.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    shouldAutoComplete = true;
    for (int position = 0; position < AutoCompleteAdapter.getCount(); position++) {
        if (AutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position).userName.equalsIgnoreCase(s.toString())) {
            shouldAutoComplete = false;
            break;
        }
    }

}

 private class DoAutoCompleteSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<UserSearchItem>> {


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<UserSearchItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<UserSearchItem> autoComplete = new ArrayList<UserSearchItem>();

        //get info from DB (userName, userId, userFbId)

                  UserSearchItem item = new UserSearchItem(userName, userId, userFbId);
                  autoComplete.add(item);
              }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return autoComplete;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<UserSearchItem> result) {
        AutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
        for (UserSearchItem s : result)
        {
            AutoCompleteAdapter.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for an answer: fill the adapter with your data in the constructor:

```
   UserSearchAdapter adapter = new UserSearchAdapter(this, data);
```

And add a constructor in your adapter class like this:

```
    public class UserSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserSearchItem> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    int count = 0;
    private List<UserSearchItem> mItems;

    public UserSearchAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.context = context;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public UserSearchAdapter(Context context, List<UserSearchItem> items) {
       super(context, 0, items);
       this.context = context;
       vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       mItems = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final UserSearchItem i = mItems.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
           Log.d("adapter", "in here");
           UserSearchItem si = (UserSearchItem) i;
           v = vi.inflate(R.layout.user_search_item, null);
           final TextView title = (TextView) v
              .findViewById(R.id.tv_userSearchName);
        if (title != null)
            title.setText(si.userName);
     }

    return v;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## Initalization ##

AutocompleteTextview actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etSearchPlace);

## set list response of your web API in adapter ##

SpringArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter<String>(mcontext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);

## set adapter to Autocomplete Textview ##

actv.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


## set your drop down layout in custom adapter##
 public class CustomAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                             List<T> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(15);
                ((TextView) view).setTransformationMethod(null);
                Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(parent.getContext(), R.font.montesemibold);

                ((TextView) view).setTypeface(typeface);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```